# How can I add directories to my Azure Data Lake Gen2 Script?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am creating an azure data lake gen 2 from a .yml script and as part of creating containers, I want to  create directories inside the containers. However, it doesn't seem to accept any extra directories on top of the container.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('dataLakeGen2Name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "[parameters('accountKind')]",
      "tags": {
      },
      "properties": {
        "isHnsEnabled": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', parameters('dataLakeGen2Name'), 'default', 'interlocking-incoming')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('dataLakeGen2Name'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}', parameters('dataLakeGen2Name'), 'default', 'interlocking-processing', 'failed')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('dataLakeGen2Name'))]"
      ]
    }
```

In the last container, I want a directory of failed to be added in the container. However, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Creating directories under the ADLS Gen2 containers is not directly supported by ARM templates.

You can do a workaround by:

- Using [deployment scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template) in ARM templates
- Or running the post-deployment script manually from CLI or similar

The deployment script can perform actions that can't be directly done with standard ARM template resources

Example:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
  "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
  "name": "createDirectoryScript",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "AzureCLI",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers', parameters('dataLakeGen2Name'), 'default', 'interlocking-processing')]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "azCliVersion": "2.0.80",
    "scriptContent": "az storage fs directory create -n failed -f interlocking-processing --account-name parameters('dataLakeGen2Name') --auth-mode login",
    "timeout": "PT1H",
    "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
    "retentionInterval": "P1D",
    "identity": {
      "type": "SystemAssigned"
    }
  }
}
```